# removing more than two consecutive chars

Tags: python

I want to remove any `char` which repeats more than two times consecutive.

```
import re
re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1', 'ffffffbbbbbbbqqq')
```

it's returning me `fbq`, while I need `ffbbqq`. The goal is pre-process the string before doing a spell checking. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [204]: import re

In [205]: re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1\1', 'ffffffbbbbbbbqqq')
Out[205]: 'ffbbqq'
```

Comment: I never knew that you could do that.